# The reason behind LEDS getting dim (Water level indicator using ULN 2003)

Tags: led, water, indicator, level, uln2003

[image: Circuit diagram]

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

[image: Picture 3]

**
Whenever I switch on the circuit, the LEDs glow fully for a second and gets off. After 2-3 seconds they start glowing slowly.

What might be the reason for the above?

Answer (score 2):

Probably due to probe chemical interaction with the fluid.

What are the probes made of and
what  is the fluid type and concentration?

Using platinum probes may help prevent chemical interaction.

Use of AC also can help as average reaction may be closer to neutral.

Comment: Probes are aluminium and the fluid is water